# Processing image loading NullPointerException

Tags: processing

I am working on a processing project, and I'm trying to add code to load and display flags.

This is what the code looks like:

Inside of the setup() function, there is this code to load images:

```
PImage flag_Japan = loadImage("Flag_Japan.png");
PImage flag_None = loadImage("Flag_None.png");
```

In another file (linked to the first), there is this code outside of all functions, to declare the flags images as global variables and get them from the country names:

```
PImage flag_Japan;
PImage flag_None;

PImage getFlag(String s) {
  switch(s) {
    case "Japan": return flag_Japan;
    default: return flag_None;
  }
}
```

Finally, in a function called within draw(), there is this code to display them:

```
println(getCountry(pe.name)); //testing, prints "Japan"
image(getFlag(getCountry(pe.name)), X_MIN+5, y+5);
```

The data folder contains these files:

[image: Folder containing several files, including one called "Flag_Japan.png"]

When I run the processing code, I get a NullPointerException on the displaying code line (the one using the image() function). What is going wrong in the code? Is there a more efficient way of loading and displaying several national flags in processing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code in `setup` is actually creating two new *local* variables and loading the images into those. Since they are local to your `setup` function, the variables you're returning from `getFlag` don't have any images loaded into them (they point to `null`; hence `NullPointerException`).

**Why**
When you use a type in front of a variable name (`PImage flag_Japan = ...`) it indicates that you are declaring a **new** variable. Normally you cannot declare two variables that have the same name, but since you are doing so inside a function it is allowed. This new variable is scoped to be available only inside the function so it doesn't get confused with the other global variable with the same name.

So the global variables that you're accessing from `getFlag` never get any images loaded into them.

**Fix It**
Luckily, the fix is easy: just make sure that you only declare **one** set of global variables.

In Processing, code from any file in your project can see the code in all the other files, so this should work:

File 1:

```
// declaring global variables to be used everywhere
PImage flag_Japan;
PImage flag_None;

void setup() {
    // load images into the global variables
    // note: no PImage type here so we don't accidentally create new variables
    flag_Japan = loadImage("Flag_Japan.png");
    flag_None = loadImage("Flag_None.png");
}
```

File 2:

```
// don't re-declare the variables here
// we can access the global ones from File 1

PImage getFlag(String s) {
  switch(s) {
    case "Japan": return flag_Japan;
    default: return flag_None;
  }
}
```

Comment: @Julio974 That's a very good point on [variable shadowing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) (+1).

Comment: Thank you so much! Yes, just removing the "PImage" in the setup avoid re-declaring new variables and now fully works!